# How will I convert data in csv file to dictionary format using python

Tags: python

I have a CSV file which looks like below image:

[image]

I want to get this in dictionary format like this:

```
{'Alcolohol - related liver disease': 'Jaundice Yellow Eye, pain, swelling,', 
 'Acquired Capillary Haemangioma of Eyelid': 'Raised red or blue lesion,', 
 'Acquired Immuno Deficiency Syndrome': 'Flu-like illness,', 
 'Acute encephalitis syndrome': 'Headache, fever, confusion, stiff neck, 
  vomiting,', .......... and so on}
```

Try using this in CSV file.

Comment: Please provide some sort of attempt and then someone will gladly assist you. It seems though that you are just going to want a for loop. Loop through each row and index the first value, set it as the key. Index the second value, set it as the value.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check if the `key` *(disease)* is already assigned and `append` the `value` *(symptoms)* to the `list`.

≈ Database DeNormalization

```
import csv
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('./file.csv', 'r'))
next(csv_reader)  # skip header

disease_dict = {}
for row in csv_reader:
    disease, symptoms = row[0], row[1]
    if disease not in disease_dict:
        disease_dict[disease] = []
    disease_dict[disease].append(symptoms)

print(disease_dict)
```

P.S.
To print the dictionary in your format:

```
for key in disease_dict:
    print(key, *disease_dict[key])
```